# Seq2Seq prediction speed is slow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

i'm trying to implement a Seq2Seq model using LSTM in tensorflow (from scratch, without rnn cell), the model works fine but the predict time for one sentence is slow for me. about 2 -> 6 sec a sentence. Is that normal?

My model:

2 LSTM for encode

2 LSTM for decode

Attention mechanism

Vocabulary: 400k

Word vector dimension: 300

The prediction code is totally on CPU.

I read some paper but they don't provide prediction speed. Thank you!

Comment: Assuming your running your code on a reasonably modern machine, 2-6 seconds per example sounds slow. Did you implement your LSTM cell from scratch? It would be helpful if you provided snippets of your code.